# How do I fix my resolution?

Tags: pc, dark-souls

I recently redownloaded dark souls on a new laptop. Had a few problems with the game loading but that has been resolved in a previous question. A new problem has risen. The resolution is all stuffed into one corner while the rest of the HUD is fine. I have DSFix installed and can't find anything that can fix this (or at least what I can understand).

[image: What's going on here?]

Comment: Have you turned of the anti-aliasing in the game's options? This issue is usually related to not turning that off, which is mentioned in the DSFix installation instructions.

Answer (score 1):

To get rid off this problem you should disable anti-aliasing in options.

See more in [installation instructions](http://www.nexusmods.com/darksouls/mods/19/?).